# MYSQL texts looking weird

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am making an android application that sends some TEXT to server and other people can see those Text but the problem is here when I send the TEXT it looks like this (Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… Ø¨Ù‡ Ù‡Ù…Ù‡) in the MYSQL table inside the server and it shows the text like this (???????????) (By the way I am writing the text in Persian) to the people who get the text and also when I add some records manually inside the database it also shows like question marks on the PHONE.

I tried puting database and tables Collation to utf8_general_ci and utf8_persian_ci but it did not work.

Comment: If u insert manually by using phpmyadmin than fine??

Comment: What encoding do the http requests show?

Comment: and when I am inserting manually in PHPmyadmin it shows well inside phpmyadmin interface but in android phone it shows like question marks

Answer (score 2):

How do you send the data to the server, is it via a PHP Service? If so, I once had a problem with Cyrillic and setting the connection itself to UTF8 helped.

Here's the statement if you are using mysqli but I think there's an alternative for PDO as well.

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

Comment: yes bro it is Via PHP